# Can I get away with preg_replace() here or do I need to use preg_split()?

Tags: php, regex

I need to split (but not `preg_split()`) my title on `/`, `:` or whitespace, in that order. For example, if I split on `/`, then I don't want to bother looking for `:` or whitespace.

I thought I could do it with a regex (the input string here will **never** have HTML in it)

```
$delimiters = array('/', ':', '\s');

$title = preg_replace('@(' . implode('|', $delimiters) . ')(.*)$@', '$1 <span>$2</span>', $title, 1);
```

The regex I have will match the first space, and not bother with the others. This is not what I want.

Obviously I could `strpos()` for the other characters (`:` and `/`) and remove the `\s` from the delimiters if it found the others. This will solve the first problem.

I also want to pick the furthest right match, i.e. if splitting a sentence on whitespace, I want the last word to be matched.

Do I need to use `preg_split()` here, and preserver the delimiter or can I do it with one regex?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some example input and output? I don't think I fully understood your question.

Comment: @NullUserException I added my own answer (which hopefully answers the above), but if you can find a better solution feel free to post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's another one:

```
function alexify($title) {
    $delimiters = array('/', ':', '\s');

    $regex = '@(' . implode('|', $delimiters) . ')([^' . implode($delimiters) . ']*)$@';
    $title = preg_replace($regex, '$1<span>$2</span>', $title, 1);

    return $title;
}
```

It appears to produce the same output as your function: http://ideone.com/HVeh5

EDIT: It actually produces different output for the 3rd string. I don't know which one is supposed to be the right one.

Comment: Thanks! So your regex looks for text on the right hand side of a delimiter that doesn't contain a delimiter! Brilliant!

Comment: @alex There's one thing that hasn't been accounted for: some characters (regex metacharacters) need to be escaped for the regex to work.

Comment: So long as I only use `/`, `:` and `\s`, I should be right, right? I specifically used the @ symbols as delimiters so I didn't need to escape the `/`. :)

Comment: @alex Yeah, in that case you should be OK. But there's always [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

While I was waiting to be answered, I came up with this, and it works!

```
$delimiters = array('/', ':');

if ( ! preg_match('@(?:' . implode('|', $delimiters) . ')@', $title)) {
   $delimiters[] = '\s';
}

$tokens = preg_split('@(' . implode('|', $delimiters) . ')@', $title, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

$tokens[count($tokens) - 1] = '<span>' . end($tokens) . '</span>'; 

$title = implode($tokens);
```

Comment: @NullUserException `alex()`? Haha! Well, sort of. I forgot to mention that these strings should only ever have one `:` or `\`. But perhaps I should make it more bulletproof. Thanks!

Comment: @NullUserException Actually, that behaviour is OK. :) Also, looks like my `/` didn't come out in my previous comment. (think I accidentally did the escape)

Comment: Are you just trying to put the first "word" from right to left inside a tag?

Comment: @NullUserException I want the right hand side of the last `/` or `:`, or if none of those chars are present, than I want the last word. Don't ask me - this is how the designer wants titles displayed! :P